# How to clear laggy chicken farm

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, performance

I've irresponsibly made an auto breeding chicken farm on a multiplayer server. Unfortunately, I left my character AFK and the farm grew beyond any possibility of getting close, for it causes horrible lag.

I'm now looking for a way to clear the farm from a distance – or for a client-side mod that will remove chickens from rendering so that I'll be able to kill them while they are invisible. Mods that require server access aren't an option since it's not my server.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Couldn't you just start walking until the chickens are unloaded?

Comment: The farm is next to my house. And even if it wasn't - I'm not going to leave it here so other players will get trapped by the lag.

Comment: After the chickens are de-spawned you can come back and disassemble it.

Comment: Neutral mobs do not despawn. At least not in farms. Otherwise, it wouldn't be possible to leave your farm and go away and find the mobs on their places.

Comment: Did not know that.  While [verifying](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Mobs#Passive_mobs) I noticed that chickens will follow you if you have SEEDS.  You might try leading them into a trap like that.

Comment: of course they follow you. This is the way I got the first members of my farm. However, leading army of 100+chickens over the server could be considered as an enemy invasion by server admins I guess :)

Comment: We march at sunset, because it's not a surprise attack if the army starts yelling at the sunrise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far, I discovered a nice solution. I had to make a splash Potion of harming II. Then I approached the farm **without looking at it** (like while you play slenderman). It seems that Minecraft renderer is smart enough not to lag completelly when you do not look at the laggy area.

Comment: There are mods that add commands that will auto-kill (passive) mobs, although I don't the names of any of them

Comment: It would be nice if the server could prevent mob spawning in a chunk where mob count has exceeded certain amount. I'm not the administrator of this particular server, but with hoppers and droppers anybody can build such an insane farm, so I'm sure there must be a known solution, and I'd be happy to offer it to server admins.

Comment: While vanilla doesn't support this, but some of the bukkit plugins mentioned [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/22893/88) might be helpful, I think there's one allowing to limit the amount of chicken per chunk or similar. Of course you could also use MCedit...

Comment: Yeah, had I the necessary permissions, I'd just write `//butcher`. I'll have look at the plugins.

Comment: The lag from chickens is mostly from the slip-shod way minecraft handles the sounds they make. Thus, if you can find a client side plugin that removes sound processing, it will help a ton.

Comment: Turning off sound turns of sound processing (according to minecraft ingame resource statistics). If you tur off sound it dissapears from resource graph.

Comment: Does that mean that removing sound removes most of the lag from having tons of chickens?

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia No, that won't help at all.

Answer (score 2):

you can go in a world editor (or NBT editor to modify the files directly) and remove all chickens from the chunk

Comment: I'm sorry, I've forgotten to say that it happened on SMP server and that I do not have any character with enough permissions to use plugins that would spare me of them chicken.